# 貪欲算法の算出プログラムついて、とりあえず第一段階の質問

Tags: c

貪欲算法を求めたく、とりあえず第一段階として、ファイルに書いてあるすべての文を出力させたいのですが、なぜか一番と二番だけしか出てきません。C言語の参考書など色々参考にしながらプログラムを行ったので不備はないと思ったのですが、どこがおかしいのでしょうか。（ちなみに、「knap10.txt」には１０個のデータが打ち込んであります。）

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int i,j;
    int nitem=0;
    double capacity;
    double weight,value;
    char file_name[NMOJI],name[100];
    printf("Data Flie Name: ");
    scanf("%s",file_name);
    if((fp=fopen(file_name,"r"))==NULL){
        printf("%s:そのファイルを開けることはできません。\n",file_name);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Knapsack capacity: ");  scanf("%lf",&capacity);
    printf("データファイル名： %s\n",file_name);
    printf("ナップサック容量： %f\n",capacity);
   
     fscanf(fp,"%d",&nitem);
    if(nitem>MAX_ITEM){
        printf("アイテム数を%3d以下にしてください.\n",MAX_ITEM);
        return -1;
    } else{
        while(fscanf(fp,"%s%lf%lf",name,&weight,&value)==3){
          printf("%-10s %5.1f %5.1f\n",name,weight,value);  
    }
    for(i=0;i<nitem;i++)
        fscanf(fp,"%lf",&weight);
    for(i=0;i<nitem;i++)
        fscanf(fp,"%lf",&value);

   
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
}
```

「knap10.txtに打ち込んだ文」

```
一番  39.0   42.0
二番  13.0   12.0
三番　68.0   45.0
四番  15.0   5.0
五番  10.0   2.0
六番  20.0   61.0
七番  31.0   89.0
八番  15.0   32.0
九番  41.0   47.0
十番  16.0   18.0
```

期待しているプログラム

```
$ ./a.out
Data Flie Name: knap10.txt
Knapsack capacity: 121
データファイル名： knap10.txt
ナップサック容量： 121.000000

一番     39.000000 42.000000
二番     13.000000 12.000000
三番     68.000000 45.000000
四番     15.000000 5.000000
五番     10.000000 2.000000
六番     20.000000 61.000000
七番     31.000000 89.000000
八番     15.000000 32.000000
九番     41.000000 47.000000
十番     16.000000 18.000000
```

実行結果

```
$ ./a.out
Data Flie Name: knap10.txt
Knapsack capacity: 121
データファイル名： knap10.txt
ナップサック容量： 121.000000
一番      39.0  42.0
二番      13.0  12.0
```

Comment: knap10.txt の三行目だけ全角の空白になっているのが原因ではないでしょうか。

Comment: 質問内容とは関係がありませんが、`fscanf(fp,"%d",&nitem);` という処理がありますので、本来は `knap10.txt`  の1行目に `10`(入力データ数)が入るはずなのですね？

Comment: @cublik  回答ありがとうございます。確かに三行目が全角の空白となっていました。

Comment: @metropolis  「fscanf(fp,"%d",&nitem);」は、先生のプログラムを参考にしただけなので、どのような役割を果たしているのかがわかりませんでした。たしかに、knap10.txtには、データ数が格納されています。